# could not be able to add action item buttons in action bar

Tags: android

I have created a project with MasterDetailedFlow Activity, now I want to add action item buttons on action bar like following:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuItem add = menu.add("Add City");
    MenuItem delete = menu.add("Delete");
    add.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    delete.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    return true;
}
```

the following line is added in onCreate method:

```
// Show the Up button in the action bar.
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Now I'm unable to see the action item buttons in Actionbar please tell me how to make be shown there...

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you set show as action always?

add.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

Comment: Still action buttons are not visible!

Comment: I have tried the same code snippet in my phone running android 4.1.2 . The action items are visible. Have you set any style or theme for the activity in the manifest file? or just tap on the action bar to verify if the action items have appeared with black text color.